$(\frac{\int f dx}{b-a})^ p \leq \frac{G(b) - G(a)}{b-a}$

Question: Given $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, show that $f \in L^p(\mathbb{R} ) \iff \exists\,\, G:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, bdd., continuous and non-decreasing such that for all $b > a$, we have


$$\left(\frac{\int_{[a,b]} f dx}{b-a}\right)^ p \leq \frac{G(b) - G(a)}{b-a}$$

Now, I was able to show the forward direction by Holder's inequality, wherein I got $G(x) = \int_0^x |f|^p$. However, I am unable to show the backward direction.
The hint is to use Lebesgue differentiation theorem + $\int_a^b G' \leq G(b) - G(a)$ for right-continuous, increasing $G:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.
All I can get from this are a few scattered facts. First, by Lebesgue diff. theorem:

$f \in L^1 \implies F'(x) = \lim_{r \rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{2r} \int_{x-r}^{x+r} f (s) ds = f(x)$ for almost every $x$.

Then, by the second theorem on differentation of measures:

For $G$ as above, we have that $\int_a^b G' \leq G(b) - G(a)$. This implies that $\frac{\int_a^b G' dx}{b-a} \leq \frac{G(b) - G(a)}{b-a}$. But I'm not sure how to use this since we have no (obvious) relation between the LHS above and the LHS here.

For $F$ as above, since $f$ is integrable we have $F$ is absolutely continuous, and so $\int_a^b F'(s) ds = F(b) - F(a)$.



You have to write $|\left(\frac{\int_{[a,b]} f dx}{b-a}\right)|^ p \leq \frac{G(b) - G(a)}{b-a}$ sine the $p-$ power (without absolute value) may not be defined.
Note that $G$ is differentiable almost everywhere.
$|f|^{p}\le G'$ a.e.  by Lebesgue's differentiation Theorem. Now $\int |f|^{p} \le \int G'\le G(b)-G(a)<\infty$.

Thank you! Why is $f$ differentiable? Do you mean that $|f|^p \leq G'$ by Lebesgue decomposition?

Sorry, I typed $f'$ for $f$. @algebroo

Got it. Thank you so much!
